# How to create a Select query that counts matching items

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have an Access table like this:

```
ID   nume   nume_proiect
6857    1   Proiect2
6858    1   Proiect3
6859    1   Proiect4
6860    1   Proiect5
6876    10  Proiect4
6879    10  Proiect4
6878    10  Proiect5
6877    10  Proiect5
6861    2   Proiect3
6862    2   Proiect4
6863    2   Proiect5
6864    3   Proiect2
6865    3   Proiect3
6866    3   Proiect4
6867    4   Proiect2
6868    4   Proiect4
6869    4   Proiect5
6870    5   Proiect3
6871    5   Proiect4
6872    5   Proiect5
6873    6   Proiect1
6874    6   Proiect2
6875    6   Proiect3
```

Now I want to select only the values from column nume_a2c that are ONLY IN Project3, Project4, Project5 AND NOT IN Project1, Project2. The result of the query should be: 2 , 5

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking please read

Comment: Why is this tagged for both 'mysql' and 'oracle' in addition to 'ms-access'?

Comment: i've changed the tags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    select DISTINCT nume_a2c        
from (
    SELECT nume_a2c,nume_proiect
    FROM table1
    WHERE nume_a2c IN
    (
    SELECT nume_a2c
    FROM table1
    where nume_proiect in ('Proiect3','Proiect4', 'Proiect5')
    )
    and nume_a2c not in
    (
    SELECT nume_a2c
    FROM table1
    where nume_proiect in ('Proiect1', 'Proiect2')
    )
    group by nume_a2c, nume_proiect ) as BB

    group by nume_a2c
    having count(nume_proiect) = 3 

    ;
```

This should work, you can check it [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/496e61/48/0)

Comment: It will not work, since it will return also 1 and 6.

Comment: the result using your query is 10, 2, 5. I need values from nume_a2c that are on all 3 projects (project 3,4 and 5) and 10 is not on project 3.

Answer (score 1):

mysql way:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/496e61/29

```
SELECT DISTINCT t.nume_a2c
FROM table1 t

INNER JOIN (
  SELECT SUM(nume_proiect IN ('Proiect1', 'Proiect2')) as criteria,
  nume_a2c,
  SUM(IF(nume_proiect = 'Proiect3',1,0)) as p3,
  SUM(IF(nume_proiect = 'Proiect4',1,0)) as p4,
  SUM(IF(nume_proiect = 'Proiect5',1,0)) as p5

  FROM table1 
  GROUP BY nume_a2c
  ) t1
ON t.nume_a2c = t1.nume_a2c
  AND t1.criteria=0 
  AND t1.p3 > 0 AND t1.p4 > 0 AND t1.p5 > 0
```

Comment: and project5 they want

Answer (score 1):

You probably need some LEFT JOIN here to get all the nume_a2c from Proiect3, 4 and 5.

```
SELECT * FROM tableName t
LEFT JOIN tableName t1 ON t1.nume_a2c = t.nume_a2c
LEFT JOIN tableName t2 ON t2.nume_a2c = t.nume_a2c 
WHERE t.nume_proiect = 'Proiect3'
  and t1.nume_a2c is not null
  and t2.nume_a2c is not null 
  and t1.nume_proiect = 'Proiect4'
  and t2.nume_proiect = 'Proiect5'
```

Comment: Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression '(t1.nume_a2c = t.nume_a2c and t1.nume_proiect ='Proiect4') LEFT JOIN A2C t2 ON (t2.nume_a2c=t.nume_a2c and t2.nume_proiect='Proiect5'.

Comment: I think that access doesn't use parenthesis in LEFT JOIN. See my edit.

Answer (score 1):

This has been tested in Access 2010:

```sql
SELECT nume_a2c
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT nume_a2c, nume_proiect FROM table1)
WHERE 
    nume_proiect IN ('Proiect3','Proiect4','Proiect5')
    AND 
    nume_a2c NOT IN (
        SELECT nume_a2c
        FROM table1
        WHERE nume_proiect IN ('Proiect1','Proiect2')
    )
GROUP BY nume_a2c
HAVING COUNT(*) = 3
```

Comment: This code works fine for this dataset, but if such row (7000,    2,   'Proiect4')  will be, your code wont return, coz COUNT() will be equal 4 for that value, this is why `group by nume_a2c, nume_proiect` is required

Comment: By the way, I have the same query)